# know when NSTextField becomes first responder

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

How can I know when an NSTextField becomes the first responder (i.e. when the user click on it to activate it, but before they start typing).  I tried controlTextDidBeginEditing but this doesn't get called until the user types the first character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass the NSTextField and overwrite the

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
```

method, defined in the NSResponder class (a superclass of NSTextField), like so:

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {

  BOOL flag=[super becomeFirstResponder];

  if(flag)
  {
    // text field will become first responder
  }

  return flag
}
```